# Safari css hack working on IE8

Tags: html, css

In a html page support these browsers Mozilla Firefox14, IE8, Safari5.1.1, Chrome19.
Since to support all these browsers I have to use css hacks in order to maintain the proper alignment of the elements on page.

Below is the css:

For Mozilla Firefox and IE8:

```
.dis_stats
{
position:absolute;
margin-top:-30px;
margin-left:-190px;
background:#E0E0E0;
width:141px;
height:80px;
_position:relative;
_margin-top:-460px;
_margin-left:115px;
}
```

For Safari & Chrome:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.dis_stats
{
position:absolute;
background:#E0E0E0;
margin-top:-30px;
margin-left:731px;
width:141;
height:80;
}
}
```

Now what is happening on Mozilla it is running perfectly. But on IE8 it is applying the properties defined for Safari & Chrome and if I remove any of the Safari & Chrome's property then it will pick the same from intended properties (i.e defined for IE8 & Mozilla).

I am not getting any clue why is this happening. Anyone please suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: The only thing that is different is the `margin-left`, you are aware of that?

Comment: yes, but the point is why it is picking up the css meant for SAFARI & CHROME?

Comment: There has to be more to it, show us the full css file somewhere.

Comment: If your CSS bave to be so different from one browser to another you're doing it very wrong. :-/

Comment: @pzin what other option i can opt for if not one css?

Comment: This is why you don't rely on hacks, you have no way of guaranteeing that it is going to effect the right browser.

Comment: For the browser support you've listed, there really shouldn't be any need for CSS hacks. If you'd said IE6 or Firefox 3.0 I could understand it, but the browsers you've listed shouldn't have any cross-browser compatibility issues with the styles you're using. I can't understand why you'd need such different styles for them. What is it that you're trying to achieve; maybe we can help you do it without hacks?

Comment: @Spudley Actually on Safari/Chrome, div left position was going distorted. That is why I have used css hack with different margin-left:731px; instead of margin-left:-190px;. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: it gets distorted by 541 pixels??? there's no browser bug that does that, I guarantee you that. I can only assume that you've got some other CSS somewhere else that is interfering with it, but I can't tell you what is causing it without seeing it in action. Would you be able to set up a jsFiddle example (or similar) that demonstrates the problem so we can see what's happening?

Comment: @Spudley May be I am not very good in explaining my problem. It is getting distorted by 541pixels only because It is defined in the css hack "dis_stats" for SAFARI/CHROME as mentioned in question. Actually, this is the issue that it is picking the properties from the css hack "dis_stats" intended for SAFARI not from normal "dis_stats" intended for all other browsers.I'll try to setup a demo ASAP.

Comment: Webkit and Gecko render extremely similarly, I'm still unclear as to why you need a WebKit only hack?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to work out a version that complies with standards and doesn't need hacks.
But if you must hack, you can consider conditional comments specially for IE 8 with separate stylesheet that fixes its problems:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css" src="path/to/ie-only-style.css">
<![endif]-->
```

This doesn't really explain what's wrong with IE, but can solve some IE-specific problems without using too much time (at cost of maintainability).